# Is there a programming language for designing and web publishing electronic circuits?

Tags: diagram, publishing, circuit

there are good languages to publish math contents on the web. But, is there any such language for electronic circuits diagrams. Which can help you design circuit diagrams, save in several formats [.pdf,.ps, .djvu etc] and publish on the web? By, publishing on the web I don't mean first save in some picture format and then use html to import. I mean an editor/language which can do both.
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps something like this? http://opencircuitdesign.com/

Comment: thanks. though i've seen it before. but was lazy to give it a try. can you please tell me, whether xcircuit is able to publish on the web?

Answer (score 0):

http://opencircuitdesign.com/xcircuit/
I've not tried this personally, but the description says it can!

Comment: i had to use magic for some of my projects. it is a very powerful and nice software but only for linux users. i regret i had to use it through cygwin. xcircuit is not exception, i presume?

Comment: xcircuit requires X-server, so on windows you would have to keep X-server running to work with xcircuit.

Answer (score 0):

Circuit design is usually done graphically.

The nicest output I know is produced by `gschem`, but it is only possible to export Postscript and various image formats.

Comment: Postscript can be easily converted to most other formats. `ps2pdf` is available on most distros, for example. From there, you can turn the PDF into many formats - Adobe have an online pdf2html tool http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/access_onlinetools.html.

Comment: Well the procedures need to be handled manually then. Actually, I was looking for something that automate all these. There is language like jsMath for circuit drawing on the web?